# Kuberenetes - Custom domain ingress

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-elb

I have a cluster IP service and a Ingress. What should my custom domain name point to if I need to route traffic using Ingress? Backend is plain http.

Do I have to create a AWS Loadbalancer with target groups pointing to k8s nodes? And use domain alias pointing to aws loadbalancer? I was reading this [K8s article](https://www.ibm.com/cloud/blog/how-to-use-the-ingress-application-load-balancer-to-expose-an-app-outside-a-kubernetes-cluster) and they're pointing to a subdomain.

`Ingress.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2022-08-05T00:50:41Z"
  generation: 1
  labels:
    app: testing
  name: httpd
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: www.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: httpd
            port:
              number: 8080
        path: /
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - www.example.com
    secretName: tls-secret
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

`service.yaml`:

```
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2022-08-05T00:50:41Z"
  labels:
    app: testing
  name: httpd
  namespace: default
spec:
  clusterIP: 100.65.xxx.xx
  clusterIPs:
  - 100.65.xxx.xx
  internalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ipFamilies:
  - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    name: httpd
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

Comment: I think you're looking for [aws-load-balancer-controller](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/aws-load-balancer-controller.html) and [external-dns](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/external-dns).

Answer (score 1):

Yes you have to create the Load Balancer however that will auto managed by the K8s service.

You can use the Nginx or other ingress controller as per requirement.

You can checkout this Nice official doc from AWS : https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/network-load-balancer-nginx-ingress-controller-eks/

Once you deploy the Nginx ingress controller it will manage the ingress resource and the Nginx controller will get the public LB.

Example :

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - anthonycornell.com
    secretName: tls-secret
  rules:
  - host: anthonycornell.com
    http:
      paths:
        - path: /apple
          backend:
            serviceName: apple-service
            servicePort: 5678
        - path: /banana
          backend:
            serviceName: banana-service
            servicePort: 5678
```